# How to Outlook Reply with attachment c#

Tags: outlook, vsto, reply

When I reply to incoming mail, attachs are deleted. How do I add attachments to new mail with vsto addin?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the original email attachments are removed from the new item? Why is it a problem? That is the expected behavior. Note that embedded **images** attachments are copied to the new message.

You can save the original attachments by looping through the `MailItem.Attachments` collection and calling `Attachment.SaveAsFile`. You can then add the attachments to the new message by calling `MailItem.Attachments.Add`.